# Images not displaying in IE8 when a width is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8

Whenever I include an image and set a width for it, it stops displaying in IE8. It displays fine in IE7 either way.

```
= image_tag 'image.png', :height => 36
```

Works great

```
= image_tag 'image.png', :width => 104, :height => 36
```

No go

The order of these attributes makes no difference either. Has anyone encountered this before?
I am able to fix my problem by not including a width, but I'd prefer to have a width set.

Comment: How is it positioned? Are you using a float or relative? The order of attributes should not matter in any case.

Comment: Have you tried using :size => '104x36' ?

Comment: @tadman It is floating actually. I tried put the same image elsewhere on the page not floated and it actually shows up just fine with a width...

Comment: @KyleC, it didn't work with the :size attribute either.

Comment: What the heck is `size`?

Comment: IE 8 and floated elements are not friends. If this is inside of a floated element, the floated element must be given a matching width using CSS. You should be using `:style => 'width:104px;height:36px'` for both elements.

Comment: Size is a Rails helper. I'm trying your suggestion now.

Comment: Ah, that did the trick! Thanks. Feel free to answer the question.